# How to resolve a hotkey conflict?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, script, automation, autohotkey, hotkeys

I bound <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to an action, for example:

```
!Space::Send, Foo
```

Now how to trigger the original <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>'s action (as shown in the image below) through code?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [docs](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols) you need to add the `$` modifier or define `#UseHook` to prevent Send() from triggering its own hotkeys.

Comment: As a side note, you may want to upvote [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410915/7881859) for bringing syntax highlighting for AHK scripts.